# Netcore razor generating wrong URL with CloudFront

Tags: c#, razor, amazon-cloudfront

Mu project use netcore,razor engine and Amazon CloudFront, when I use Html.Pager, the links has generated with server url instead cloudfront url.

var pager = Html.Pager(Model.PagingFilteringContext).QueryParam("pagenumber")

Somebody know why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved in cloudfront configuration.
Changes the behaviors -> cache based on selected request headers, change to whilist and choose the headers.

That its...